# VS 2012 is creating new folder on startup

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Each time I run VS 2012 it creates new folder under My Documents visual studio 11. It is pointing to start pages folder under this folder. Most probably there is some configuration there which is pointing to this folder for start pages and code snippets(it creates this folder too). 
Can you please tell me how and where I can change this configuration.

Comment: What does it do if these folders already exist?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the default paths - see the `Options` dialog, then go to `Projects And Solutions > General`.

(Am looking at a different version, but I don't think it will have moved too far from here).

Comment: yes that was causing creation of other folders. I have changed the paths. Now it only creates the start pages and I am not able to figure out from where to change path for this.

Answer (score 0):

And you also need to change path in Import and export settings

Answer (score 0):

Open Regedit then browse to:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0
```

In here you can set the default directories for a number of different items.